# How to build an Android UI with various rectangles on it?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a UI on Android, with various rectangles on it.

It should look like this:
https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/android/Labs/ModernArtUI/modernUI.mp4

My idea is to bulid a RelativeLayout with ImageViews in it, but actually I don't know how to start, for example create 2 columns, in the first column with 2 and in the second column with 3 rectangles with different colours.

Could someone show me an example? It would be enough to have an example with 2 different sized rectangles in a relative layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this with LinearLayouts only. But I think this is what you are looking for. Setting the layout_weight is the key.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:background="#00ff00" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.3">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="#0000ff" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:background="#ff0000" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Haywire!Thank you for your comment!

I don`t understand something: how can I divide the left rectangle intpo multiple rectangles?

Sorry for these questions, but I am new to Android.

Thank you very much!

Comment: OK, I found the solution: add one more vertical layout inside the linear layout.

Thanks again!